# How to replace this statement " StringIO import StringIO " ( avaialbe in python 2 ) in python 3

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Obviously , I'm new to Python.

I would like to use StringIO in my code below : to extract example.xml

```
 import os
os.chdir('d:/py/xml/')


from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def parseXML(xmlFile):
    """
    Parse the xml
    """
    f = open(xmlFile)
    xml = f.read()
    f.close()

    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
    context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
    for action, elem in context:
        if not elem.text:
            text = 'None'
        else:
            text = elem.text
        print (elem.tag + ' => ' + text)

if __name__ == "__main__":

parseXML("example.xml")
```

But I keep getting this msg

***Syntax Error: from io import import StringIO: d:\py\xml\example.py, line 621
File "d:\py\xml\example.py", line 6, in ?
  from io import import StringIO***

I did google but it said to import the io model and use io.StringIO or io.BytesIO for text or Data...

Can anyone please tell me, how can I actually do that ?

Thanks

Comment: `from io import StringIO` is what the message is telling you to do, I think.

Comment: The error message you pasted was pasted from a run of a different code, in which you just an extra `import` in your statement (`from io import import StringIO`). Remove that `import` and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python3, `StringIO` is in `io`:

```
from io import StringIO
```

(Not `from io import import StringIO`, the keyword `import` goes only once.)

Note the the `2to3` script will do this change for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you , Now I just got this error ------>   File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 512, in lxml.etree.iterparse._read_more_events (src/lxml\lxml.etree.c:98819)  Is this something with the installation ?

Comment: @JPC: What you posted in your comment is the location of an error, not the actual error message, so I have no idea what the reson might be.  But it's for sure that that issue is unrelated to your original question, so please ask a new one.

Comment: Thank , Sven I will post the new one.. Super new at programming. sorry

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148166/builtins-typeerror-reading-file-objects-must-return-plain-strings-error-in-xp)

Answer (score 5):

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit:

> The StringIO and cStringIO modules are gone. Instead, import the io module and use io.StringIO or io.BytesIO for text and data respectively.

`from io import StringIO`