# builtins.TypeError: reading file objects must return plain strings : Error in Xpath - python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

Here's my code :

```
import os
os.chdir('d:/py/xml/')


from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def parseXML(xmlFile):
    """
    Parse the xml
    """
    f = open(xmlFile)
    xml = f.read()
    f.close()

    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
    context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
    for action, elem in context:
        if not elem.text:
            text = 'None'
        else:
            text = elem.text
        print (elem.tag + ' => ' + text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseXML("example.xml")
```

I am trying to extract this xml file below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<zAppointments reminder="15">
    <appointment>
        <begin>1181251680</begin>
        <uid>040000008200E000</uid>
        <alarmTime>1181572063</alarmTime>
        <state></state>
        <location></location>
        <duration>1800</duration>
        <subject>Bring pizza home</subject>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <begin>1234360800</begin>
        <duration>1800</duration>
        <subject>Check MS Office website for updates</subject>
        <location></location>
        <uid>604f4792-eb89-478b-a14f-dd34d3cc6c21-1234360800</uid>
        <state>dismissed</state>
  </appointment>
</zAppointments>
```

Got this error, not sure what I have done wrong , please help.

***builtins.TypeError: reading file objects must return plain strings***

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Also, is there a reason for creating the `tree` variable? If it isn't needed, you could try passing the file `f` to `iterparse` functions instead of reading it all in and creating a `StringIO` file-like object from its contents.

Comment: builtins.TypeError: reading file objects must return plain strings
File "d:\py\xml\example.py", line 27, in <module>
  parseXML("example.xml")
File "d:\py\xml\example.py", line 19, in parseXML
  for action, elem in context:
File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 491, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src/lxml\lxml.etree.c:98616)
File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 512, in lxml.etree.iterparse._read_more_events (src/lxml\lxml.etree.c:98819)

Comment: Does it work to skip the StringIO and pass the real file `f` to `lxml.etree.parseiter`?

Comment: HI Blckknght , you mean this 
    context = etree.iterparse(f)

Comment: Yeah. You'll have to get rid of (or comment out) the earlier bits that read and close `f` up above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
os.chdir('d:/py/xml/')


from lxml import etree
#from io import StringIO

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def parseXML(xmlFile):
    """
    Parse the xml
    """
    f = open(xmlFile)
    #xml = f.read()
    #f.close()

    #tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
    context = etree.iterparse(f)
    for action, elem in context:
        if not elem.text:
            text = 'None'
        else:
            text = elem.text
        print (elem.tag + ' => ' + text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseXML("example.xml")
```

So here's the final code just in case someone needs it, Thank you Blckknght